# Ring of formal multivariate Laurent series as a consecutive localisation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, laurent-series, localization

How do we localise a the ring of formal power series $\mathbb C[[x, y]]$ to get the field of multivariate Laurent series $\mathbb C((x))((y))$? If $S_x$ and $S_y$ are the multiplicative closed sets $\{x^n: n\geq0\}$ and $\{y^n: n\geq0\}$, respectively, do we have
$$S_y^{-1}S_x^{-1}\mathbb C[[x, y]]=\mathbb C((x))((y))?$$

Comment: Observation: $S_y^{-1}S_x^{-1}\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$ does not contain $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{-n}y^n\in \mathbb{C}((x))((y)).$

Comment: I agree. In fact $\mathbb C((x))((y))$ cannot be obtained from $\mathbb C[[x, y]]$ by consecutive localisation.